How can I use related node titles as a token and insert as the value of the field I need?
I have a field with multiple values through which I link to other nodes. Using the ECA: Event - Condition - Action module, I would like to take the headers of nodes linked through this field and insert them into the text field separated by commas every time a new material is created.
The documentation contains an example of the model.
I would be grateful for any help in solving this problem using an example from the documentation. I tried different ways, but all I could do was substitute the number of linked nodes as the value of the field.
